# Unity Asset for "LookAt" doesnt work? Basic character look controller?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation

Ok I am trying control where my character directs the upper half of his body (sometimes just head) as promised by this asset, which uses Unity's LookAt transform properties to perfect the effect : https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/perfect-look-at-107800

Ive followed the instructions and looked at the samples but my setup won't behave correctly - see screenshots - even when I play with what axis is the forward (coming from blender I thought it was -Z but didn't work) - the head tilts a weird way/does not follow cube exactly.

Problem:

[image]
Setup:

[image]

Armature:

[image]

Most LookAt scripts are similar - what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are placing the script in the wrong place, sometimes it changes a lot because the relative position of the children and the father.
So probably the script is in the wrong place or you should add localrotate after lookat in order to get the correct rotation

Comment: Can you give an example/expand on what you mean by this? Ive tried setting all rotations to 0, still no luck

Comment: Look at and the try to rotate different angles to reach the perfect one due the relative rotation

Comment: I have. And none are working. Thats what Im trying to communicate here